# Excel 2010 - sumproduct with date criteria

Tags: excel-2010

I have a formula to calculate interest per account per financial year.
Cell A is the date of the transaction
Cell B is the Bank eg. CBA
Cell C is the Account type eg. Smart Access
Cell D is the transaction description, so if the description eg. Interest
Cell E is the amount

This formula work:

```
=IF(AND($A$2<>"Date",$A$2:$A$724 >= DATEVALUE("01/07/2014"),$A$2:$A$724 < DATEVALUE("01/07/2015")),SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$724=$I2)*($C$2:$C$724=$J2)*($D$2:$D$724="Interest")*($E$2:$E$724)))
```

but when I update the formula where "DATEVALUE("01/07/2016")" to change the financial year, the results I now get is FALSE

```
=IF(AND($A$2<>"Date",$A$2:$A$724 >= DATEVALUE("01/07/2015"),$A$2:$A$724 < DATEVALUE("01/07/2016")),SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$724=$I2)*($C$2:$C$724=$J2)*($D$2:$D$724="Interest")*($E$2:$E$724)))
```

Sample data

```
Date            Bank/ADI     Account        Transaction Description Amount
30/06/2015  CBA          Smart Saver    Interest                $100.00
```

Can someone please help as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: Not without sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would humbly suggest that you abandon the older [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) in favor of the vastly more efficient [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5).

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E,$A:$A, ">="&DATE(2014, 7, 1),$A:$A, "<"&DATE(2015, 7, 1),$B:$B, $I2,$C:$C, $J2,$D:$D, "Interest")
```

Alternately, with **2014** in J1 then,

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E,$A:$A, ">="&DATE($J$1, 7, 1),$A:$A, "<"&DATE($J$1+1, 7, 1),$B:$B, $I2,$C:$C, $J2,$D:$D, "Interest")
```

With **01-Jul-2014** in J1 then,

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E,$A:$A, ">="&$J$1, $A:$A, "<"&EDATE($J$1, 12),$B:$B, $I2,$C:$C, $J2,$D:$D, "Interest")
```

I really did not understand exactly what the `AND($A$2<>"Date",$A$2:$A$724 >= DATEVALUE("01/07/2015"),$A$2:$A$724 < DATEVALUE("01/07/2016"))` portion was trying to accomplish in a standard formula formula but the SUMIFS can easily compensate date criteria. It would be even easier of you put the year (or the BOM of the fiscal year) into a cell and referenced that.